# creating a file with the content of a folder

Tags: file-command

Is it possible to create a file which contains the information (the contents) of a certain folder? For example:

```
cat /folder >> file
```

I also tried

```
touch /folder >> file
```

I should add that I need the folders and their folders and files in a recursive way

Comment: "Folder" contains other folder and files.

Comment: Using `cat file1 file2 > file3` i was able to transfer the text(content) of file1 and file2 to file3.  I'm trying to do the same, but with the files that are in "folder".

Comment: There is also the question if the order is important, if the directory is recursive?

Comment: I'm not quite sure.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would do it by

```
ls /path/to/folder > outputfile
```

If you want to see the recursive contents of folders within folders with file permissions, you can use

```
ls -lR /path/to/folder > outputfile
```

Comment: Thank you @Pilot6 , it lists the names of the folders and files in a vertical fashion. In other words, creates a file that lists the folders and files in a specific folder.

Comment: By the way, the command `ls -lR /path/to/folder > outputfile` does the something similar, also adding the the chain of subfolders that are inside the folder, and their respective content(-R). -l gives extensive information. Also thanks for your help @Owen Hines !

Comment: @Pilot6 , may I add the command `ls -lR /path/to/folder > outputfile` in your answer as an additional option?

Comment: @Sam , Yeah, sorry that I didn't get it quite right.

Comment: @Sam Sure you can add it as an option with a description what it does. I will approve it.

Comment: @Sam I rejected your edit because it did not explain the usage of the `-lR` parameters of `ls`. "Also works" is not an explanation. You need to write WHY you prefer to use `ls` with these options.

Comment: Besides `-R` is recursive. You did not ask for a recursive list in your question.

Comment: I thought that the explanation would appear on the summary. I forgot to add  that I also wanted what is inside each folder, hence -R.

Comment: OK. I will add it myself.

Comment: @Pilot6 , I see you add an explanation on the command line but ass a suggestion. Could you add it on your answer?

Comment: I did add it to my answer.

Comment: Now I see it! And it's an easy and complete explanation. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Do something like

```
ls >> outputFile
```

This will pass the output of the ls command to a specified file.

For example, if you are in a folder that contains:

- `File1`
- `File2`
- `File3`

Then running `ls >> outputFile` will make a file called `outputFile` that contains

`File1 File2 File3`

Comment: I run that command a the result is a file called homedir which contains the names of all the folders and files located in pwd. I'm trying to do something similar to `cat file1 file2 > file3`.

Comment: Exactly. I did that. Maybe I should use -R, since that would give me all the content of a chain of folders.

Comment: I mark because it gave me a partial result. But I still need to figure it out. I  also not certain of but the exercise asked me to do. I mean, is it similar to `cat file1 file2 > file3`? Thanks for you help!

Comment: That'd be nice @Owen Hines , but it seems that I don't have enough reputation to ask in the chat.

Comment: Why do append with `>>`? And `echo` is not needed.

Comment: [Useless use of backticks/subshells](http://porkmail.org/era/unix/award.html#backticks). Why not simply `ls >> outputfile`?